python - iterate through json log nested objects
I have a log file that I'm importing and then would like to pull out some key:value.  Some are nested within the output.  I have a sample json log file and I have been using json.load(s) but I'm only able to get to certain high level sections.  I need to find a way to dig deeper to pull some of the information.  If possible into a csv file.
Sample Log:
{
  "status_code": 200,
  "response_headers": {
    "Date": "Thu, 06 Jun 2024 21:08:20 GMT",
    "Content-Type": "application/vnd.snypr.app-v3.0+json",
    "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains",
    "Cache-Control": "private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate",
    "X-FRAME-OPTIONS": "DENY",
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "X-XSS-Protection": "1 ;mode=block",
    "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
    "Content-Security-Policy": "frame-ancestors 'self' nix.net; default-src 'self' *.nix.net; object-src 'self' *.nix.net data: blob:; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'self' *.nix.net https://edge.fullstory.com https://rs.fullstory.com http://iph.zoominsoftware.io/widget.js data: blob:; style-src 'self' *.nix.net //fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'; font-src 'self' *.nix.net https://fonts.gstatic.com 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src 'self' *.nix.net //edge.fullstory.com https://rs.fullstory.com //nix-prod.zoominsoftware.io //documentation-be.nix.com wss://nix.net:443 data: blob:; img-src 'self' *.nix.net //rs.fullstory.com data: :; child-src 'self' *.nix.net blob:;"
  },
  "reason": "",
  "json_body": {
    "status": "OK",
    "result": {
      "data": {
        "totalIncidents": 2,
        "incidentItems": [
          {
            "violatorText": "6.45.2.14",
            "lastUpdateDate": 1711676781065,
            "violatorId": "6.45.2.14",
            "incidentType": "HighRiskActivityIp",
            "incidentId": "19875819288",
            "incidentStatus": "COMPLETED",
            "riskscore": 0,
            "assignedUser": "Nil Jhain",
            "priority": "High",
            "reason": [
              "ResourceGroup: lopGroup - Palo Alto",
              "Policy: ISOC - Apache Log4j RCE Attempt NGF",
              "Threat: Vulnerabilty detected"
            ],
            "entity": "Activityip",
            "workflowName": "SOCTeamReview",
            "url": "configurableDashboards/view?&type=incident&id=19875819288",
            "isWhitelisted": false,
            "watchlisted": false,
            "tenantInfo": {
              "tenantid": 47,
              "tenantname": "lopGroup",
              "tenantcolor": "#e34bcb",
              "tenantshortcode": "LGR"
            },
            "statusCompleted": true,
            "sandBoxPolicy": false,
            "parentCaseId": "",
            "casecreatetime": 1711660064545,
            "bulkactionallowed": true,
            "type": "HighRiskActivityIp",
            "caseEventStartTime": 1699191830798,
            "caseEventEndTime": 1711676755393,
            "solrquery": "index = violation  and @policyname=\"ISOC - Apache Log4j RCE Attempt NGF\" and @ipaddress=\"6.45.2.14\" and @resourcegroupname=\"lopGroup - Palo Alto\" and @tenantname=\"lopGroup\" and generationtime between \"11/05/2023 07:43:50\" \"03/28/2024 20:45:56\"",
            "policystarttime": 1699191830798,
            "policyendtime": 1711676756393
          },
          {
            "violatorText": "5.335.24.214",
            "lastUpdateDate": 1711613598761,
            "violatorId": "5.335.24.214",
            "incidentType": "HighRiskActivityIp",
            "incidentId": "19875814036",
            "incidentStatus": "COMPLETED",
            "riskscore": 0,
            "assignedUser": "Gallav Smingh",
            "priority": "High",
            "reason": [
              "ResourceGroup: lopGroup - Palo Alto",
              "Policy: ISOC - Apache Log4j RCE Attempt NGF",
              "Threat: Vulnerabilty detected"
            ],
            "entity": "Activityip",
            "workflowName": "SOCTeamReview",
            "url": "://configurableDashboards/view?&type=incident&id=19875814036",
            "isWhitelisted": false,
            "watchlisted": false,
            "tenantInfo": {
              "tenantid": 47,
              "tenantname": "lopGroup",
              "tenantcolor": "#e34bcb",
              "tenantshortcode": "INGR"
            },
            "statusCompleted": true,
            "sandBoxPolicy": false,
            "parentCaseId": "",
            "casecreatetime": 1711595601351,
            "bulkactionallowed": true,
            "type": "HighRiskActivityIp",
            "caseEventStartTime": 1686455128927,
            "caseEventEndTime": 1711613588858,
            "solrquery": "index = violation  and @policyname=\"ISOC - Apache Log4j RCE Attempt NGF\" and @ipaddress=\"5.335.24.214\" and @resourcegroupname=\"lopGroup - Palo Alto\" and @tenantname=\"lopGroup\" and generationtime between \"06/10/2023 22:45:28\" \"03/28/2024 03:13:09\"",
            "policystarttime": 1686455128927,
            "policyendtime": 1711613589858
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}


import json 
  
# Load the JSON data  in a dictionary
with open('C:\samplealertlog.json', 'r') as f: 
    data = json.load(f) 
  
# Iterate through the JSON dictionary, need to get to sub-arrays
for item in data: 
    print(item["violatorId"], item["incidentId"],item["Policy"], item["solrquery"], item["tenantname"])`


Please provide an example of something specific you're trying to extract from the sample data, and what you tried to do so. Explain what you expected, and what happened instead. The bit of code you provided seems to iterate over ['json_body']['result']['data']['incidentItems'], so it would appear you already know how to traverse the nested dictionary, but the code also suggests that's in a separate file. Am I understanding correctly that the code you shared is what you tried, but it's not actually working, and you expect it to give you those fields for that part of the JSON data?

Assuming C:\samplealertlog.json contains the JSON data you shared, the first bit of code reads the entire chunk of data into a nested dictionary:
with open('C:\samplealertlog.json', 'r') as f: 
    data = json.load(f) 

To get to the violatorId, incidentId, etc. of the various incidentItems, you want to drill down into the nested dictionary:
incident_items = data['json_body']['result']['data']['incidentItems']

Now, incident_items points to the list at that position in the nested dictionary.
Then, you can iterate over its elements:
for item in incident_items:
    print(item['violatorId'], item['incidentId'], item['solrquery'])

However, it appears you also want 'Policy' and 'tenantname'. The latter is inside another dictionary value in the item and the former is hidden away in a string element of the 'reason' list.
So, a bit more work is needed to get those:
    print(item['tenantInfo']['tenantname'])  # note case-sensitivity, `name`
    for reason in item['reason']:
        if reason.startswith('Policy: '):
            print(reason)

If I save your data as sample.json and run the following:
import json

with open('sample.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

    incident_items = data['json_body']['result']['data']['incidentItems']

    for item in incident_items:
        v_id, i_id, query = item['violatorId'], item['incidentId'], item['solrquery']
        tenant_name = item['tenantInfo']['tenantname']  # note case-sensitivity, `name`
        for reason in item['reason']:
            if reason.startswith('Policy: '):
                policy = reason.split('Policy: ')[1]
                break

        print(f'Violator: {v_id}, Incident: {i_id}, Tenant: {tenant_name}\n'
              f'Query: {query}\n'
              f'Policy: {policy}\n')

The output is:
Violator: 6.45.2.14, Incident: 19875819288, Tenant: lopGroup
Query: index = violation  and @policyname="ISOC - Apache Log4j RCE Attempt NGF" and @ipaddress="6.45.2.14" and @resourcegroupname="lopGroup - Palo Alto" and @tenantname="lopGroup" and generationtime between "11/05/2023 07:43:50" "03/28/2024 20:45:56"
Policy: ISOC - Apache Log4j RCE Attempt NGF

Violator: 5.335.24.214, Incident: 19875814036, Tenant: lopGroup
Query: index = violation  and @policyname="ISOC - Apache Log4j RCE Attempt NGF" and @ipaddress="5.335.24.214" and @resourcegroupname="lopGroup - Palo Alto" and @tenantname="lopGroup" and generationtime between "06/10/2023 22:45:28" "03/28/2024 03:13:09"
Policy: ISOC - Apache Log4j RCE Attempt NGF


Appreciate your insight and assistance.  I could only get "results" and "data".  I was unable to figure out how to get the below nested data.  I kept getting an error that the Key was not found, so I knew I was not accessing the right level of the array but with my limited python knowledge, could not get to the right level.  I will test and follow up with my success.  Cheers

Have a close look at data['json_body']['result']['data']['incidentItems'] and your data and figure out how they relate. Also keep a close eye on lists [] vs dictionaries {} in the data. Both are accessed (indexed) with square brackets, but a dictionary has arbitrary keys, while a list is always indexed with consecutive integers.
